# dagre-d3 svg labels not rendering in Meteor

Tags: meteor, d3.js, svg, dagre-d3

I'm somehow unable to apply the SVG label example here: http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/svg-labels.html into Meteor.

The svg_edge_label gets created, but somehow won't appear on the edge! Any idea what's unique about Meteor that doesn't allow this to render? (My Meteor app is using the perak:dagre-d3 package)

main.html:

```
<head></head>
<body></body>
```

main.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import './main.html';

var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph()
    .setGraph({})
    .setDefaultEdgeLabel(function () { return {}; });

svg_edge_label = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
edge_tspan = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','tspan');
edge_tspan.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', 'xml:space', 'preserve');
edge_tspan.setAttribute('dy', '1em');
edge_tspan.setAttribute('x', '1');
edge_link = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a');
edge_link.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'http://google.com/');
edge_link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
edge_link.textContent = 'IE Capable Edge link';
edge_tspan.appendChild(edge_link);
svg_edge_label.appendChild(edge_tspan);

g.setNode(0, {label: "A"});
g.setNode(1, {label: "B"});
g.setNode(2, {label: "C"});

g.setEdge(0, 1, { labelType: "svg", label: svg_edge_label});

var render = new dagreD3.render();
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg"),
    svgGroup = svg.append("g");
render(d3.select("svg g"), g);
```